# Swift：Instance member 'layer' of type 'UIView' cannot be used on instance of nested type

Tags: ios, swift, nested

Swift. As code shown bellow, there are two nested views. But when I access `self`、`layer` property in inner view Class, the Xcode throw a build error named `Instance member 'layer' of type 'UIView' cannot be used on instance of nested type`. 
Actually, I know this is mainly because the builder is not clear enough about who is the `self` indicates.
Could anybody helps to cover my meets?

```
class MTFilterView: UIStackView {

    class FilterCellView: UIView {
        @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

        override class func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            layer.cornerRadius = 15
        }
    }
}
```